# pandas summing rows before NaN condition is encountered

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas df of the format below:

```
    Value1   Value2   Value3
     -10      -20      NaN
     -5       -10      20
     -15       -10     NaN   
     -20       -5      15
```

I am looking to do a rolling sum of `Value1` and `Value2` based on the `NaN` encountered in `Value3`
So the final result looks like:

```
Value1    Value2    Value3
-15       -30        20
-35      -15         15
```

Here each row is a cumulative sum for (`Value1` and `Value2`) of the values from the last time `Value3` had a `non NaN` value.

Except for looping through I am out of ideas on how to achieve this...any thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: On SO you're required to post your own code attempt. Here you simply `groupby()` Value3 being NaN. The rest is trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
out = df.groupby(df['Value3'].isna().cumsum()).sum().reset_index(drop=True)
print(out)

# Output
   Value1  Value2  Value3
0     -15     -30    20.0
1     -35     -15    15.0
```

Focus on groups:

```
>>> df['Value3'].isna().cumsum()
0    1  # group1, rows 1 and 2
1    1
2    2  # group2, rows 3 and 4
3    2
Name: Value3, dtype: int64
```